# Smartly converting array of hashes to CSV in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv

I need to convert an array of hashes in a CSV file. The various methods I found involve inserting in the array the hash values:

```
class Array
  def to_csv(csv_filename="hash.csv")
    require 'csv'
    CSV.open(csv_filename, "wb") do |csv|
      csv << first.keys # adds the attributes name on the first line
      self.each do |hash|
        csv << hash.values
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately this method requires that each element in the array is complete, for example when I have this array it won't even return a valid csv:

```
myarray = [
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3},
  {bar: 2, baz: 3},
  {foo: 2, bar: 4, baz: 9, zab: 44}
]
```

I'm looking for a way to create a csv that finds all the possible headers, and assigns the values in correct order, adding empty spaces where needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about:

```
class Array
  def to_csv(csv_filename="hash.csv")
    require 'csv'
    # Get all unique keys into an array:
    keys = self.flat_map(&:keys).uniq
    CSV.open(csv_filename, "wb") do |csv|
      csv << keys
      self.each do |hash|
        # fetch values at keys location, inserting null if not found.
        csv << hash.values_at(*keys)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I would do it in this way. It's quite brute force because it needs to find all the headers that exist and also needs to fill the empty elements..

```
class Array
  def to_csv(csv_filename='test.csv')
    require 'csv'

    headers = []
    self.each {|hash| headers += hash.keys}
    headers = headers.uniq

    rows = []
    self.each do |hash|
      arr_row = []
      headers.each {|header| arr_row.push(hash.key?(header) ? hash[header] : nil)}
      csv_row = CSV::Row.new(headers, arr_row)
      rows.push(csv_row)
    end
    csv_table = CSV::Table.new(rows)
    File.open(csv_filename, 'w'){|file| file << csv_table.to_s}
  end
end
```

Take a look at [CSV::Row](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html) and [CSV::Table](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html) classes. I find them handy.