# Creating a CSV from a hash

Tags: ruby, csv, hash

I need help understanding how to dump my hash contents into a csv.  I found the following post that is exactly what I'm trying to do, but unfortunately there is no example on how to call the method so that it will write to a file.

original post
[Smartly converting array of hashes to CSV in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066365/smartly-converting-array-of-hashes-to-csv-in-ruby)

```
       def to_csv(csv_filename="hash.csv")
         require 'csv'
         # Get all unique keys into an array:
         keys = self.flat_map(&:keys).uniq
         CSV.open(csv_filename, "wb") do |csv|
           csv << keys
           self.each do |hash|
             # fetch values at keys location, inserting null if not found.
             csv << hash.values_at(*keys)
           end
       end   
end
```

My array of hashes is called results and looks something like this:
(Note: some keys have nil values)

```
[{:name =>"Mike", :job = "Teacher", :status = "single"},
{:name=> "Joe", :job =>nil, :status = "married"},
{:name =>"Sally", :job = "Nurse", :status = "single"}]
```

I would like to dump the entire contents of the results hash into a CSV file for further manipulation.  My problem is I can't figure out how to get the results into csv file.  When I run:

```
results.to_csv
```

nothing happens, no file is created.  I thought I may have to first seed a blank file, but even then, no contents go into the file.

Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and why this isn't working.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Please explain "nothing happens". If literally nothing happens when you run `results.to_csv`, your Ruby is broken. Odds of that being the case are extremely small. If you are getting an error, then please include it in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define this method as an instance method of the class Array.

```
class Array
  def to_csv(csv_filename="hash.csv")
    require 'csv'
    # Get all unique keys into an array:
    keys = self.flat_map(&:keys).uniq
    CSV.open(csv_filename, "wb") do |csv|
      csv << keys
      self.each do |hash|
        # fetch values at keys location, inserting null if not found.
        csv << hash.values_at(*keys)
      end
    end   
  end
end

[{ :a=>1, :b=>2 }, { :c=>3 }].to_csv
  #=> [{:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:c=>3}]
```

Let's see what was written.

```
CSV.read("hash.csv")
  #=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", nil], [nil, nil, "3"]]
```

I infer this is an array method from the code fragment

```
self.flat_map(&:keys)
```

As the mapping is to keys, it suggests that the reiceiver is an array of hashes.(That expression could have been written `flat_map(&:keys)`.)

This method does not appear to meet your requirements.

You could save the keys and values thusly:

```
CSV.open("hash.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  arr.each do |h|
    csv << h
  end
end
  #=> [["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

CSV.read("hash.csv")
  #=> [["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: @CarySwoverland, that was the ticket.  I had to wrap it as in instance of the Array Class.  Is there anyway to accomplish this without putting in in a class?  It would be so much easier in my mind to just have it as it's own method.  Plus, I'm just curious to know why it needs to be in a class.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: pjw23, consider the instance method [Array#size](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-push). Given an array `arr`, `arr.size` is the size of the array. You could write an instance method in another class that returns the same value as follows:  `def my_arr_size(arr); arr.size; end`; that is, just make `self` in `size` an argument of `my_arr_size`. If the `Array` method has arguments and/or a block, include those arguments, together with `arr`, and the block in the method defined in another class. Is that clear?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
require 'csv'

  def to_csv(csv_filename="hash.csv")
    a = [{:name =>"Mike", :job => "Teacher", :status => "single"},
    {:name=> "Joe", :job =>nil, :status => "married"},
    {:name =>"Sally", :job => "Nurse", :status => "single"}]
    values = a.map do |h|
      h.sort.to_h.values
    end

    CSV.open(csv_filename, "wb") do |csv|
      values.each do |row|
        csv << row
      end
    end
  end
```

### EDIT

Note: This works for your case, where all your columns are in the array of hashs. For example you jave "Joe" with `:job` with value `nil`. if this is not your case, using `value_at` is the best chose

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I'm still having the same issue, it's not writing the data to the hash.csv.  I can see it on the screen when I input:  results.to_csv.  What do I need to do in order to output the data to the csv?  Thanks.

Comment: The example that I wrote works on my pc, it writes into a csv file. `SV.open(...) do.... csv << "data"` does the job